# using jquery load

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

I have very little knowledge in Jquery and I need to solve this problem soon. The following is my html and jQuery code.

```
<a class="btn1"  href="#" ref="<%=Id%>">View Activity</a>
```

on clicking this button the following event takes place.

```
$('.btn1').bind('click',function(){


              var id = $(this).attr("ref");

                $('.tinted').load('./webservices/getDetail.jsp',{"id":id});
                return false;  


            });
```

Whenever I click the get activity link the result gets displayed in class tinted but the same result gets displayed in all other .tinted class.The problem of the solution might be to get the parent of the link and then load the content in only the class of that parent.But i have no idea of how to do it. I would appreciate any help that you can give me.

Comment: Show some more of the HTML structure so we can determine the necessary DOM traversal methods.

Comment: `.tinted` is where.... next to `.btn1` or its the parent of `btn1`

Comment: You selector search for ".btn". Try "$('a.btn[ref]')" for selecting only a tags with a ref attribute. By the way: Use rel instead of ref. rel is a valid attribute for a tags.

Comment: +1 on mr_app, or just `data` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('.btn1').bind('click',function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("ref");
   var parDiv = $(this).parent("div.tinted");
   parDiv.load('./webservices/getDetail.jsp',{"id":id});
   return false;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$(this).closest('.tinted').load('./webservices/getDetail.jsp',{"id":id});
```